# Jasmine unit test skipped by my Karma configuration

Tags: node.js, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run Jasmine test using Karma runner as follows:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
        basePath: '',

        // frameworks to use
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'lib/angular/1.0.4/angular.js',
            'lib/angular/1.0.4/angular-mocks.js',
            '1820OS_*/**/*.spec.js'
        ],

        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [
            'lib/angular/1.0.4/angular-scenario.js'
        ],

        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
        reporters: ['progress'],

        // web server port
        port: 9876,

        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,

        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,

        // Start these browsers, currently available:
        // - Chrome
        // - ChromeCanary
        // - Firefox
        // - Opera (has to be installed with `npm install karma-opera-launcher`)
        // - Safari (only Mac; has to be installed with `npm install karma-safari-launcher`)
        // - PhantomJS
        // - IE (only Windows; has to be installed with `npm install karma-ie-launcher`)
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

        // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
        captureTimeout: 60000,

        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
        singleRun: false
    });
};
```

Here is the contents of my directory:

```
Structure du dossier
Le num‚ro de s‚rie du volume est 361E-0F50
C:.
|   conf.js
|   logs.txt
|   Readme.txt
|   tree.logs.txt
|   
+---1820OS_09_Code
|   +---01_directive_test_skeleton
|   |       test.js
|   |       
|   +---02_button_directive
|   |       directive.js
|   |       directive.spec.js
|   |       index.html
|   |       test.html
|   |       
|   +---03_pagination_directive
|   |       directive.js
|   |       directive.spec.js
|   |       index.html
|   |       test.html
|   |       
|   +---04_validate-equals_directive
|   |       directive.js
|   |       directive.spec.js
|   |       index.html
|   |       test.html
|   |       
|   +---05_unique-email_directive
|   |       directive.js
|   |       directive.spec.js
|   |       index.html
|   |       mock-Users.js
|   |       test.html
|   |       
|   \---06_jQuery_datepicker_directive
|           directive.js
|           directive.spec.js
|           index.html
|           test.html
|           
+---1820OS_10_Code
|   +---01 - ngLocale and the locale service
|   |       index.html
|   |       locale.js
|   |       
|   +---01_alert_directive
|   |       app.js
|   |       directive.js
|   |       directive.spec.js
|   |       index.html
|   |       test.html
|   |       
|   +---02 - locale and filters
|   |       filters.js
|   |       index_en.html
|   |       index_fr.html
|   |       
|   +---02_if_directive
|   |       directive.js
|   |       directive.spec.js
|   |       index.html
|   |       test.html
|   |       
|   +---03 - translations - i18n filter
|   |       i18nfilter.js
|   |       index.html
|   |       
|   +---03_basic_accordion_directive
|   |   |   accordion.js
|   |   |   accordion.spec.js
|   |   |   app.js
|   |   |   index.html
|   |   |   test.html
|   |   |   
|   |   \---template
|   |       \---accordion
|   |               accordion-group.html
|   |               accordion-group.html.js
|   |               
|   +---04 - customizing format in a date filter
|   |       filterCustomization.js
|   |       index.html
|   |       
|   \---04_field_directive
|       |   directive.js
|       |   directive.spec.js
|       |   index.html
|       |   test.html
|       |   
|       \---template
|               input.html
|               input.html.js
|               select.html
|               select.html.js
|               textarea.html
|               textarea.html.js
|               
+---1820OS_11_Code
|   +---01 - inner working - how digest loop works
|   |       index.html
|   |       internals.js
|   |       
|   +---02 - watchers on scope are fired often
|   |       index.html
|   |       
|   +---03 - tuning cpu - watchers - expensive computations
|   |       expensiveComputation.js
|   |       index.html
|   |       
|   +---04 - tuning cpu - watchers - remove
|   |       index.html
|   |       remove.js
|   |       
|   +---05 - tuning cpu - watchers - hidden watchers
|   |       hiddenWatches.js
|   |       index.html
|   |       
|   +---06 - tuning cpu - loops - timeout and the clock directive
|   |       clock.js
|   |       index.html
|   |       
|   +---07 - tuning memory - deep watches
|   |       deepWatch.js
|   |       index.html
|   |       
|   \---08 - tuning memory - size of a watch
|           index.html
|           
\---lib
    |   test-template.html
    |   
    +---angular
    |   +---1.0.2
    |   |       angular-mocks.js
    |   |       angular-scenario.js
    |   |       angular.js
    |   |       
    |   \---1.0.4
    |           angular-mocks.js
    |           angular-scenario.js
    |           angular.js
    |           
    +---jasmine-1.3.0
    |       jasmine-html.js
    |       jasmine.css
    |       jasmine.js
    |       MIT.LICENSE
    |       
    +---jquery-1.8.3
    |       jquery-1.8.3.js
    |       
    \---jquery-ui-1.9.2
        +---css
        |   \---ui-lightness
        |       |   jquery-ui-1.9.2.css
        |       |   
        |       \---images
        |               ui-bg_diagonals-thick_18_b81900_40x40.png
        |               ui-bg_diagonals-thick_20_666666_40x40.png
        |               ui-bg_flat_10_000000_40x100.png
        |               ui-bg_glass_100_f6f6f6_1x400.png
        |               ui-bg_glass_100_fdf5ce_1x400.png
        |               ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png
        |               ui-bg_gloss-wave_35_f6a828_500x100.png
        |               ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png
        |               ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_ffe45c_1x100.png
        |               ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
        |               ui-icons_228ef1_256x240.png
        |               ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png
        |               ui-icons_ffd27a_256x240.png
        |               ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png
        |               
        \---js
                datepicker.js
```

Here is the output of a `karma run .\conf.js`:

```
[36mDEBUG [plugin]: [39mLoading karma-* from C:\Users\julien.martin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
[36mDEBUG [plugin]: [39mLoading plugin C:\Users\julien.martin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher.
[36mDEBUG [plugin]: [39mLoading plugin C:\Users\julien.martin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-coffee-preprocessor.
[36mDEBUG [plugin]: [39mLoading plugin C:\Users\julien.martin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-firefox-launcher.
[36mDEBUG [plugin]: [39mLoading plugin C:\Users\julien.martin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-html2js-preprocessor.
[36mDEBUG [plugin]: [39mLoading plugin C:\Users\julien.martin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-jasmine.
[36mDEBUG [plugin]: [39mLoading plugin C:\Users\julien.martin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher.
[36mDEBUG [plugin]: [39mLoading plugin C:\Users\julien.martin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-requirejs.
[36mDEBUG [plugin]: [39mLoading plugin C:\Users\julien.martin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-script-launcher.
[32mINFO [karma]: [39mKarma v0.10.9 server started at http://localhost:9876/
[32mINFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser PhantomJS
[36mDEBUG [launcher]: [39mCreating temp dir at C:\Users\JULIEN~1.MAR\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-54411459
[36mDEBUG [launcher]: [39mC:\Users\julien.martin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma-phantomjs-launcher\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom\phantomjs.exe C:\Users\JULIEN~1.MAR\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-54411459/capture.js
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mResolved files:
    C:/Users/julien.martin/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js
    C:/Users/julien.martin/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/lib/angular/1.0.4/angular.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/lib/angular/1.0.4/angular-mocks.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/06 - testing - simple Jasmine test/helloWorld.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/07 - testing - services - a notificationsArchive test/archive.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/08 - testing - a controller test/admin-projects.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/09 - testing - timeout test/timeout.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/10 - testing - karma tips and tricks/tips.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_03_Code/02 - jsonp/jsonp.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_03_Code/04- unit testing with httpBackend mock/test-with-http-backend.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_03_Code/05 - promise api/promises.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_04_Code/08 -filters - array filters full example/arrayFilters.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_04_Code/09 - filters - accessiong from JavaScript/trimFilter.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/authorization.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/interceptor.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/login/login-form.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/login/login-toolbar.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/retry-queue.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/security.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/02_button_directive/directive.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/03_pagination_directive/directive.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/04_validate-equals_directive/directive.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/05_unique-email_directive/directive.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/06_jQuery_datepicker_directive/directive.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_10_Code/01_alert_directive/directive.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_10_Code/02_if_directive/directive.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_10_Code/03_basic_accordion_directive/accordion.spec.js
    C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_10_Code/04_field_directive/directive.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mWatching "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/lib/angular/1.0.4/angular.js"
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mWatching "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/lib/angular/1.0.4/angular-mocks.js"
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mWatching "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle"
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/lib/angular/1.0.4/angular-mocks.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/07 - testing - services - a notificationsArchive test/archive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/06 - testing - simple Jasmine test/helloWorld.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/10 - testing - karma tips and tricks/tips.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/09 - testing - timeout test/timeout.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/08 - testing - a controller test/admin-projects.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_03_Code/05 - promise api/promises.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_04_Code/08 -filters - array filters full example/arrayFilters.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_04_Code/09 - filters - accessiong from JavaScript/trimFilter.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_03_Code/04- unit testing with httpBackend mock/test-with-http-backend.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_03_Code/02 - jsonp/jsonp.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/02_button_directive/directive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/04_validate-equals_directive/directive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/03_pagination_directive/directive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/05_unique-email_directive/directive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/06_jQuery_datepicker_directive/directive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_10_Code/01_alert_directive/directive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_10_Code/03_basic_accordion_directive/accordion.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_10_Code/04_field_directive/directive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_10_Code/02_if_directive/directive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/06 - testing - simple Jasmine test/helloWorld.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/08 - testing - a controller test/admin-projects.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/09 - testing - timeout test/timeout.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/10 - testing - karma tips and tricks/tips.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/07 - testing - services - a notificationsArchive test/archive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_03_Code/02 - jsonp/jsonp.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_03_Code/04- unit testing with httpBackend mock/test-with-http-backend.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_03_Code/05 - promise api/promises.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_04_Code/08 -filters - array filters full example/arrayFilters.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_04_Code/09 - filters - accessiong from JavaScript/trimFilter.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_10_Code/01_alert_directive/directive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_10_Code/03_basic_accordion_directive/accordion.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_10_Code/04_field_directive/directive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/03_pagination_directive/directive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/04_validate-equals_directive/directive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/06_jQuery_datepicker_directive/directive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/05_unique-email_directive/directive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/02_button_directive/directive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_10_Code/02_if_directive/directive.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/lib/angular/1.0.4/angular-mocks.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/lib/angular/1.0.4/angular.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/lib/angular/1.0.4/angular-mocks.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/lib/angular/1.0.4/angular.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/authorization.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/interceptor.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/retry-queue.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/security.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/interceptor.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/security.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/retry-queue.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/authorization.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/login/login-form.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/login/login-toolbar.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/login/login-form.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [watcher]: [39mAdd file "C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/login/login-toolbar.spec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:\Users\julien.martin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\static/client.html
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:\Users\julien.martin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\static/karma.js
[36mDEBUG [karma]: [39mA browser has connected on socket 1vT3Y1P01r8VDgGsK7wx
[32mINFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7)]: [39mConnected on socket 1vT3Y1P01r8VDgGsK7wx
[36mDEBUG [karma]: [39mAll browsers are ready, executing
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:\Users\julien.martin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\static/context.html
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/Users/julien.martin/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/Users/julien.martin/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/lib/angular/1.0.4/angular.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/lib/angular/1.0.4/angular-mocks.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/06 - testing - simple Jasmine test/helloWorld.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/07 - testing - services - a notificationsArchive test/archive.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/08 - testing - a controller test/admin-projects.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/09 - testing - timeout test/timeout.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_02_Code/10 - testing - karma tips and tricks/tips.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_03_Code/02 - jsonp/jsonp.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_03_Code/04- unit testing with httpBackend mock/test-with-http-backend.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_03_Code/05 - promise api/promises.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_04_Code/08 -filters - array filters full example/arrayFilters.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_04_Code/09 - filters - accessiong from JavaScript/trimFilter.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/authorization.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/interceptor.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/login/login-form.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/login/login-toolbar.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/retry-queue.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_07_Code/05_security_module/tests/security/security.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/02_button_directive/directive.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/03_pagination_directive/directive.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/04_validate-equals_directive/directive.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/05_unique-email_directive/directive.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_09_Code/06_jQuery_datepicker_directive/directive.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_10_Code/01_alert_directive/directive.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_10_Code/02_if_directive/directive.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_10_Code/03_basic_accordion_directive/accordion.spec.js
[36mDEBUG [web-server]: [39mserving: C:/system/misc/1820OS_CodeBundle/1820OS_10_Code/04_field_directive/directive.spec.js
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7): Executed 1 of 132 (skipped 4)[32m SUCCESS[39m (0 secs / 0.001 secs)
[1A[2KPhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7): Executed 1 of 132 (skipped 131)[32m SUCCESS[39m (0.101 secs / 0.001 secs)
```

What am I getting wrong with my config? All **tests are skipped**...

Comment: You don't have `xdescribe` or `xit` in your test code, right?

Comment: You have a `iit` somewhere in your specs :)

Comment: Hi! I actually do. But I don't have 131 (132-1) `xdescribes/xits`. I've just performed a search on `xit` and `xdescribes` which results in **two** occurrences.

Comment: Is it fixed now? I suggested to look for `iit` because it would set focus on only this test and you have exactly 1 running.

Comment: Spot on! Thanks a lot glepretre!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I bet you have a `iit` somewhere in your test specs.

When using `iit` or `ddescribe`, you set focus only on this test/suite. This feature has been provided by Karma for a long time ([v0.04](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v004)) but not yet implemented in Jasmine. There was a long debate about that: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/pull/181.

Comment: FYI you should also look for `fit` and `fdescribe` as well

Comment: ...and `xit` and `xdescribe`

Comment: ...aaand the components developed by external teams if your app development is split between multiple teams and you depend on those external teams' packages and execute tests using a wildcard location matcher! True story!

Answer (score 12):

I had the same symptom which turned out to be caused by a misplaced paren on an 'it'.
Mine looked like:

```
it('should not have a paren immediately after this string'), function() {

}
```

Instead of how it should have looked:

```
it('should have the paren after the function block...', function() {

})
```

Comment: And this caused a skipped test (as opposed to an error or test failure)?

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that was why my test was being skipped. Gonna upvote this since I made the same mistake and your answer helped me solve it. Kudos!

Comment: The same thing happened to me. Thanks, you saved me some time.